# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'comet_ml'

Tags: python-3.x, comet-ml

I am working in a conda environment. If i do

(pytorch_env)  sudo pip3 freeze | grep comet

I get

comet-git-pure==0.19.15
comet-ml==3.1.3

But on running the python file I get

pytorch_env) ubuntu@ Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vgg_11.py", line 5, in 
    from comet_ml import Experiment 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'comet_ml'

The code is just this

```
from comet_ml import Experiment
from comet_ml.utils import ConfusionMatrix
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in conda, then you should:

```
conda install -c anaconda -c conda-forge -c comet_ml comet_ml
```

For more info, please see:
https://www.comet.ml/docs/python-sdk/releases/#installation-instructions